# Движение объекта по уравнениям от времени

Tags: python, tkinter, графика, рисование

В общем есть программка, ее идея в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку аргумент t каждый раз возрастал и фигура строилась по другим данным. Однако питон не даёт изменять переменную в функции, если её значение не зафиксировано в этой же функции. Скажите, можно ли как-то обойти это ограничение?
Если нет, как по-другому можно реализовать движение тела по заданным уравнениям? Речь про функцию but.

```
from Tkinter import *  
from math import *  
root=Tk()  
root.geometry('760x710')   
canv=Canvas(root,width=700,height=700,bg="white")  
canv.place(x=0, y=0)  
k = 3  
r = 3  
t = 0  
def but(event):  
     x = r*(k-1)*(cos(t)+(cos((k-1)*t))/(k-1))  
     y = r*(k-1)*(sin(t)-(sin((k-1)*t))/(k-1))  
     canv.create_oval(x-5+355,y-5+355,x+5+355,y+5+355,fill="red")  
     t += 0.1  


button1=Button(root,text='start',width=3,height=4,bg='gold',fg='black', font=10)  
button1.place(x = 720, y = 355)  
button1.bind("<Button-1>",but)  
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

Почитайте о областях видимости. [Статья на русском](https://python-scripts.com/scope). Вам поможет оператор `global`.

Попробуйте:

```
def but(event):
     global t

     x = r*(k-1)*(cos(t)+(cos((k-1)*t))/(k-1))  
     y = r*(k-1)*(sin(t)-(sin((k-1)*t))/(k-1))  
     canv.create_oval(x-5+355,y-5+355,x+5+355,y+5+355,fill="red")  
     t += 0.1
```

---

Полный пример с небольшими изменениями:

```
# import tkinter as tk
import Tkinter as tk
from math import cos, sin


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('760x710')

canv = tk.Canvas(root, width=700, height=700, bg="white")
canv.place(x=0, y=0)

k = 15
r = 15
t = 0.0


def but(event):
    global t

    for _ in range(100):
        x = r * (k - 1) * (cos(t) + (cos((k - 1) * t)) / (k - 1))
        y = r * (k - 1) * (sin(t) - (sin((k - 1) * t)) / (k - 1))
        canv.create_oval(x - 5 + 355, y - 5 + 355, x + 5 + 355, y + 5 + 355, fill="red")

        t += 0.1


button1 = tk.Button(root, text='start', width=3, height=4, bg='gold', fg='black', font=10)
button1.place(x=720, y=355)
button1.bind("<Button-1>", but)

root.mainloop()
```

Результат после нескольких кликов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Тут переписанный код с функцией инкрементирования через замыкание](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/fb9e2be7273e50d9059be74cdd9c99c37f1e2a83/tkinter_examples/draw_with_sin_cos__make_counter_adder.py), которое предложил **jfs**:

Comment: в этом  случае можно closure использовать ([типа make_counter()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13857/4279)). Или объект `self.t += .1`

Comment: я имел в виду что-то вроде `button.bind("<Button-1>", make_handler(t=0.0))`

Comment: @jfs, можете свой ответ с этим показать? :)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы по щелчку по экрану двигать кружок по заданной формуле, простейший способ это [turtle модуль использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import turtle
from math import sin, cos

def onclick(x, y, t=[0], k=15, r=15):
    turtle.setposition(
        x=r * (k - 1) * (cos(t[0]) + (cos((k - 1) * t[0])) / (k - 1)),
        y=r * (k - 1) * (sin(t[0]) - (sin((k - 1) * t[0])) / (k - 1)))
    t[0] += .1

turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.color('red')
turtle.onscreenclick(onclick)
turtle.mainloop()
```

так как int неизменяем в Питоне, то используется список с одним элементом, чтобы время при каждом щелчке увеличивать. Это равнозначно использованию глобальной переменной (при каждом вызове один и тот же список изменяется).

[image: circle goes in ~circles]

### Closure

В общем случае, изменяемые глобальные переменные лучше избегать. К примеру, если несколько кружков с разными параметрами одновременно двигать, можно closure использовать, чтобы эти параметры сохранить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import turtle
from math import sin, cos

def move_turtle(turtle, *, t=0, k=15, r=15):
    def onclick(x, y):
        nonlocal t
        turtle.setposition(
            x=r * (k - 1) * (cos(t) + (cos((k - 1) * t)) / (k - 1)),
            y=r * (k - 1) * (sin(t) - (sin((k - 1) * t)) / (k - 1)))
        t += .1
    return onclick

for t0 in range(4):
    turtle.onscreenclick(move_turtle(turtle.Turtle(), t=t0), add=True)
turtle.mainloop()
```

[image: several turtles moves]

### Object

Чтобы общие настройки сохранить, можно свой объект использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import turtle
from math import sin, cos

class TimeTurtle(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, t=0, *, color='red'):
        super().__init__()
        self.t = t
        self.shape('circle')
        self.color(color)

    def move(self, x, y, k=15, r=15):
        t = self.t
        self.setposition(
            x=r * (k - 1) * (cos(t) + (cos((k - 1) * t)) / (k - 1)),
            y=r * (k - 1) * (sin(t) - (sin((k - 1) * t)) / (k - 1)))
        self.t += .1


for t0 in range(4):
    turtle.onscreenclick(TimeTurtle(t0).move, add=True)
turtle.mainloop()
```

[image: red circles moves]

---

Для кода в вопросе, если намерение один кружок двигать по щелчку, а не создавать заново, можно `Canvas.move` метод использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
from math import cos, sin

class Oval:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.t = 0
        self.canvas = canvas
        x, y = self.coords()
        self.oval_id = canvas.create_oval(
            x - 5 + 355, y - 5 + 355, x + 5 + 355, y + 5 + 355, fill="red")

    def coords(self, k=3, r=3):
        t = self.t
        return (r * (k - 1) * (cos(t) + (cos((k - 1) * t)) / (k - 1)),  # x
                r * (k - 1) * (sin(t) - (sin((k - 1) * t)) / (k - 1)))  # y

    def move(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.oval_id, *self.coords())
        self.t += 0.1


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('760x710')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=700, height=700, bg="white")
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
button1 = tk.Button(root, text='start', width=3, height=4,
                    bg='gold', fg='black', font=10)
button1.place(x=720, y=355)

o = Oval(canvas)
button1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: o.move())
root.mainloop()
```

Это минимально изменённый код из вопроса к которому добавлен `Oval` класс и показано как `move()` метод можно реализовать (других возможных проблем код не касается).